# jQuery currently checked radio button value shows always first button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, checked

I have a javascript like below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<input type="radio" class="gal_location" name="gal_location" value="0"> All
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="gal_location" class="gal_location" checked="checked" value="11">Sivasagar</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="gal_location" class="gal_location" value="3">Guwahati</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="gal_location" class="gal_location" value="9">Jorhat</li>

<script>                        
if($('.gal_location').is(':checked')) { 
    var location_id = $("input:radio[name=gal_location]").val();     
}
alert('Location id is '+location_id);

</script>
```

Now I expect to get an alert of `Location id is 11`,but instead I am getting an alert of `Location id is 0`

[Code sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb3tQ/)

Comment: change `input:radio[name=gal_location]` to `input:radio:checked`

Comment: `$("input:radio[name=gal_location]").val();` this returns the value of the first radio button which it encounters with the name gal_location, so to get the value of the selected radio button you should specify `:checked`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:checked` to get checkedradio button value

```
var location_id = $("input:radio[name=gal_location]:checked").val()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pb3tQ/1/)